# How to assign csv field value to SQL query written inside table input step in Pentaho Spoon

Tags: postgresql, csv, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I am pretty new to Pentaho so my query might sound very novice.

I have written a transformation in which am using CSV file input step and table input step.
Steps I followed:

1. Initially, I created a parameter in transformation properties. The
   parameter birthdate doesn't have any default value set.
2. I have used this parameter in postgresql query in table input step
   in the following manner:

   ```
   select * from person where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM birthdate) > ${birthdate};
   ```
3. I am reading the CSV file using CSV file input step. How do I assign the birthdate value which is present in my CSV file to the parameter which I created in the transformation?

   (OR)
4. Could you guide me the process of assigning the CSV field value directly to the SQL query used in the table input step without the use of a parameter?

Answer (score -1):

> ## TLDR;
>
> I recommend using a "database join" step like in my third suggestion below.
>
> See the **last** image for reference

## First idea - Using Table Input as originally asked

Well, you don't need any parameter for that, unless you are going to provide the value for that parameter when asking the transformation to run. If you need to read data from a CSV you can do that with this approach.

- First, read your CSV and make sure your rows are ok.
- After that, use a select values to keep only the columns to be used as parameters.
- In the table input, use a placeholder (?) to determine where to place the data and ask it to run for each row that it receives from the source step.

Just keep in ming that the order of columns received by the table input (the columns out of the select values) is the same order that it will be used for the placeholders (?). This should not be a problem with your question that uses only one placeholder, but keep that in mind as you ramp up using Pentaho.
[image: first idea (csv > select values > table input)]

## Second idea, using a Database Lookup

This is another approach where you can't personalize the query made to the database and may experience a better performance because you can set a "Enable cache" flag and if you don't need to use a function on your where clause this is really recommended.
[image: second idea (csv > database lookup))]

## Third idea, using a Database Join

That is my recommended approach if you need a function on your where clause. It looks a lot like the Table Input approach but you can skip the select values step and select what columns to use, repeat the same column a bunch of times and enable a "outer join" flag that returns the rows without result from the query
[image: third idea (csv > database join)]

> ### ProTip: If you feel the transformation running too slow, try to use multiple copies from the step ([documentation here](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/.09+Transformation+Steps#.09TransformationSteps-LaunchingSeveralCopiesofaStep)) and obviously make sure the table have the appropriate indexes in place.

Answer (score -2):

Yes there's a way of assigning directly without the use of parameter. Do as follows.

Use `Block this step until steps finish` to halt the `table input step` till `csv input` step completes.

[image: full_ktr]

Following is how you configure each step.

**Note**:

1. Postgres query should be `select * from person where EXTRACT(YEAR
   FROM birthdate) > ?::integer`
2. Check `Execute for each row` and `Replace variables in` in Table input step.
3. Select only the birthday column in `CSV input step`.

[image]

Comment: The Blocking step serves no function here, the Table Input step will wait until it gets input from the CSV input step.

Comment: @matthiash Thanks +1 for your comment. its works without that as well. But I have read somewhere that Table input steps initialize as soon as ktr starts can't find the documentation though that's the reason I have added that.

Comment: I'm not sure what happens during initialization, perhaps it connects to the db at that point. But no queries will be executed before the step receives rows when using input row data as parameters. Without such parameterization, the query will be executed immediately. As for the blocking step, it does nothing when it doesn't receive any rows

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon Thank You for the solution, it works fine. But I have a query for you. If I have got a very big dynamic sql query and I am using "?" as the place holder it will not be user friendly and the developer will have to provide inputs in a particular sequence for it to work. So is there any way by which we can assign csv input to Kettle variables and use these variable in the sql.

Comment: @Dex Yes in that large query you have to place `?` in all the places you want to have your variable and the variable value that's coming from the previous step should be duplicated as much as you have `?` in your query. only way is ctrl+R in Notepad++ ;)

Comment: @Dex A select step in front of the table output step is often helpful. You can select the fields you need, in the order you need, and even have duplicates if needed if you rename to unique names.